# Get the columns where value is changing timeseriesly

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe has more than 200 columns. Sample Dataframe looks like

```
Date        Tkr col1    col2    col3
20210101    APD 20.0    19.0    15.0
20210101    BCD 20.0    19.0    15.0
20210102    APD 19.0    19.0    15.0
20210102    BCD 20.1    19.2    15.0
```

I'm trying to extract the columns from `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, where values of these columns are changing `daily` for any `Tkr`. For example `col3` is not changing, for any `Tkr` on any `Date`, but the value of `col1` is changing for every `Tkr` & `col2` is changing for any one `Tkr`, so i'm trying to get `col1` and `col2`.

I'm thinking to implement it with groupBy 'Date' & `Tkr`, but after that, i need help to do this.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use `nunique`:

```
>>> df.iloc[:, 2:].nunique().loc[lambda x: x > 1].index.tolist()
['col1', 'col2']
```

Comment: what if want to get the rows, only for which if values of col1 or col2 or col3 is different from the previous row?

Comment: In this case, what is the expected output?

Comment: if i put Tkr = APD in second row, then output will be row1, 3 only. Not row 2, because row 2 is same as row 1.